# Let A and B be n by n matrices. Suppose A is invertible. Show that AB is similar to BA.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose $A$ is invertible. Show that $AB$ is similar to BA.

I started with $BA = P^{-1}(AB)P$, but I'm drawing a blank now.

Comment: Have you tried plugging anything in for $P$ to see what happens?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you remember what $A^{-1}A$ equals?

Comment: A^-1A = In. Also, yes this is homework. I'm stuck. Since this is a proof I don't know where to go, since everything has to be theoretical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $AB=BA$, and A is invertible, then we have ${A^{-1}}ABA=BA$, there exist $P=A$, such that ${P^{-1}}ABP=BA$.

Comment: It isn't given that AB=BA.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.